# Jquery Pop up Form no funciona

Tags: jquery, css, formularios

Para no ensuciar mucho por aquí, pongo el código a través de JSFiddle.

Me explico un poco, estoy siguiendo un tutorial de la web de Jquery para crear un form que salga a través de un pop up, pero como podéis ver en el enlace de a continuación:
https://jsfiddle.net/synysevend90/v2p56zLp/
Puedo ver el form sin a verle dado al botón, y claro el botón pues tampoco hace nada, claro ya no se si es porque le falta CSS o porque no lo llego a comprender del todo

Comment: Buenas @Alberto , podias poner el manual que estas siguiendo ?¿

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form Diria que es el oficial no?

Comment: ¿Has probado en tu localhost ? Copiando y pegando el codigo de manual funciona perfectamente.
A la hora de llevarlo a tu proyecto revisa MUY BIEN el cierre de etiquetas HTML, que tengas acceso a las librerias CSS y JS que cargas y que los nombres de clases e IDs en el JS coinciden exactamente con las del HTML

Comment: es lo que me extraña que todo copiado funciona perfectamente, pero digo hago solo una prueba con el form que es lo que necesito y no era capaz revisare etiquetas aver.

Comment: Vale segui uno con bootstrap que me resulto mucho más facil ya que de Jquery no entiendo aun mucho. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Mejor añade el código aquí. No ensucia, sino que mejora el sitio. Lee [ask] y [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo el problema y la solucion
Aqui lo puedes comprobar
https://jsfiddle.net/xarlySpain/mf1txrva/

Al parecer no has cargado bien los JS en la pagina https://jsfiddle.net/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes que incluir

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js

Comment: los tengo añadidos pero voy a ver, aparte que es el dle ejemplo y como decimso arriba ese sabemos que va

Comment: Vale segui uno con bootstrap que me resulto mucho más facil ya que de Jquery no entiendo aun mucho. Gracias por la ayuda.